# ASP MVC Login with hashed password problem on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, cryptography

For a new website I am using the built-in Crypto function of .NET

First the problem : everything works locally but when I publish my website on my VPS then I can't login because the Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword returns false for some reason.

Some pieces of my code :

**Register :**

```
        var passwordSalt = Crypto.GenerateSalt(32);

        var accountInfo = new AccountInfo
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            Email = model.Email,
            Password = Crypto.HashPassword(model.Password + passwordSalt),
            PasswordSalt = passwordSalt,
```

**Login :**

```
        if (Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(accountInfo.Password, model.Password + accountInfo.PasswordSalt))
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Deze inloggegevens zijn verkeerd. Probeer opnieuw!");
        };

        var tResult = await accountService.SaveAccountInfoAsync(accountInfo);
```

I have used this before and never had any problems. Is there something wrong on my VPS?

Comment: Did you find the problem? Looks like I'm having the same situation.

Comment: @CribAd This was a long time ago but I think it was due the machineKey in my web.config.